# Knockout.js 3.1.0 binding input name and id properties using $index context

Tags: knockout.js

I'm building a cart system using Knockout.js. Currently,  I'm storing the "Orders" in an observableArray called lineItems and using a knockout foreach to generate a table row with all the required form inputs.

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: lineItems">
  <tr>
    <td><input data-bind="value: upc" name="Orders.upc"></td>
    <td><input data-bind="value: name" value="Orders.name"></td>
    ...
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Everything is working just fine, however, I'd like to edit the name attribute for each form input so that each row added by knockout's foreach loop has a unique name. Specifically, I'm trying to change the ending HTML from this:

```
  <tr>
    <td><input data-bind="value: upc" name="Orders.upc"></td>
    <td><input data-bind="value: name" value="Orders.name"></td>
    ...
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input data-bind="value: upc" name="Orders.upc"></td>
    <td><input data-bind="value: name" value="Orders.name"></td>
    ...
  </tr>
```

To this:

```
  <tr>
    <td><input data-bind="value: upc" name="Orders.0.upc"></td>
    <td><input data-bind="value: name" value="Orders.0.name"></td>
    ...
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input data-bind="value: upc" name="Orders.1.upc"></td>
    <td><input data-bind="value: name" value="Orders.1.name"></td>
    ...
   </tr>
```

I'm really not sure how to go about this (I'm new to knockout.js). I'm thinking I need to use the attribute binding along with the $index context, but I'm not sure how to go about doing that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `attr` binding...

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: lineItems">
   <tr>
      <td><input data-bind="value: upc, attr: {name: 'Orders.' + $index() + '.upc'}"></td>
      <td><input data-bind="value: name, attr: {name: 'Orders.' + $index() + '.name'}"></td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: This works. I literally figured this out just before you posted this answer. For some reason, I was thinking this was going to be a lot more complicated.